# Throwing an exception in Haskell when the object being returned is not a string.

Tags: haskell, exception

So I'm writing a program in Haskell that receives a number n telling it to return the nth prime number starting at 2 being the 1st prime number. That part of the program works however what I don't understand is how to also have the program throw an exception when the number is 0 or less.

```
pr :: Int -> Int
pr n = (filter(\x -> (getter) == []) [2..]) !! (n-1)
```

The getter references another method I wrote that is solving the prime problem. It is working fine.

Comment: Find the docs for a function that you're familiar with that throws an error, click the Source button, and have a look at what they do. One example would be `!!`

Comment: I don't have one that I'm familiar with since this is my first experience with haskell

Comment: to see about (!!), click [here](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(!!)). then [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-), and [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#%21%21). and [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#negIndex). to read more about your subject, try [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) and search for "guards" there.

Answer (score 6):

By default, if no equation for a function matches the given arguments, you get a runtime error:

```
fromJust :: Maybe a -> a
fromJust (Just a) = a
-- No case for Nothing
-- fromJust Nothing throws error at runtime
```

However, this doesn't work for numbers. Instead, guards will do a similar thing:

```
assertOver0 :: Int -> ()
assertOver0 n | n > 0 = ()
-- No case for n <= 0
-- assertOver0 (-1) throws error at runtime
```

While this is the default behavior, it is bad style to have incomplete patterns/guards. Instead, explicitly cause an error with `error` or `undefined`:

```
pr n | n >= 0    = filter (null . getter) [2..] !! n
     | otherwise = error "Table flip"
-- undefined is just like error, except that error lets you give an error message
-- and undefined doesn't (undefined is more useful when you know it will never
-- be evaluated, and you don't need to give an error message)
-- undefined :: a; error :: String -> a
-- That is, they can take on any type you want them to have, because whatever code
-- is after them will never be executed anyway
-- I took liberties with your definition of pr. Your filtering function didn't use
-- x, so I wrote what I think you meant. I also made it 0-indexed.
-- Prelude.null checks for [], but doesn't incur an Eq constraint, so I replaced
-- (== []) with it.
-- Parens are not needed around the filter, because function application has
-- the highest precedence.
```

Haskell also has a more sophisticated exception mechanism in [`Control.Exception`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html), but you probably don't need that here. In general, exceptions and partial functions are looked down upon, (because you can only handle them in `IO`) and you should strive for monads like `Maybe` or `Either` instead.

```
import Control.Monad
pr n = do guard $ n >= 0 -- guard True = Just (); guard False = Nothing (in this case)
          return $ filter (null . getter) [2..] !! n
pr 2 = Just 5
pr (-1) = Nothing
```

All this is unnecessary, though. `(!!)` already errors on negative indices

```
ghci> "abc" !! -1
*** Exception: Prelude.!!: negative index
```

So we're back to where we started:

```
pr n = filter (null . getter) [2..] !! n
```

There's also [a library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/listsafe-0.1.0.0/candidate/docs/Data-List-Safe.html) that redefines list operations (including `(!!)`) to be monadic instead of partial.

Comment: Further minor improvement: use [`null`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null) instead of `(== [])`.  Shorter and doesn't incur an `Eq` constraint :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, basically everything is just a library function. As such it can easily be found with online search engines. That includes error handling. Thus you may [ask Hayoo for `error`](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=error), or [for `raise`](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=raise), or [for `throw`](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=throw). All three exist – but `raise` only in different flavours, specialised to particular libraries, whereas [`throw`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:throw) and [`error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:error) are part of `base` and thus of “Haskell itself”.

- `throw` can be used to produce properly typed exceptions and is suitable if you may at some point, in your program itself, want to *catch* / analyse the errors.
- `error` is mostly useful to just *crash the program* while producing a (hopefully) useful diagnostic message on the terminal, which seems to be what you want here.

The type of `error` is<sup>†</sup>, as of GHC-8,

```
error :: HasCallStack => String -> a
```

The `HasCallStack` is a recent addition which allows the program to tell you *where* in your code the error occured. This doesn't change the way you use the function though; in older versions of GHC the type was simply

```
error :: String -> a
```

That means, you just give `error` some *error message* and then use it as “the result” of any function, no matter what the result type of that function is actually supposed to be. In your case,

```
pr n | n >= 0     = ...
     | otherwise  = error "Table flip"
```

If you give this function a negative number, it will then not give any actual result but crash the program with the message `Table flip` and, in GHC>=8, also tell you that this error happened within `pr`.

You'll probably want to also know *where `pr` was called*, to actually debug the problem. You can yourself use the GHC call-stack simulation for this:

```
import GHC.Stack

pr :: HasCallStack => Int -> Int
pr n | n >= 0     = ...
     | otherwise  = error "Table flip"
```

Note that I didn't need to change the implementation in any way, I just added the `HasCallStack` constraint.

---

<sup>†</sup>

<sub>If you look in [the documentation, as of GHC-8.2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:error), you'll be shown a rather scarier signature</sub>

```
error :: forall (r :: RuntimeRep). forall (a :: TYPE r). HasCallStack => [Char] -> a
```

...don't worry about that, these are just implementation details raising of meanigful errors throwing is in fact not so naturally supported by the Haskell language.

Answer (score 0):

**Administrivia**
Other answers have given you some good text so I'm going to be code-heavy and explanation light here.  If something still isn't clear then please do comment and I'll try to fill it in (or any of you regular S.O. answerers can beat me to it).

**The Answer**

You presented a problem where the input of `n <= 0` is invalid:

```
pr :: Int -> Int
pr n = (filter(\x -> (getter) == []) [2..]) !! (n-1)
```

The easy solution is to match with a pattern or guard and manually throw an exception:

```
pr :: Int -> Int
pr n | n <= 0    = error "NO!"
     | otherwise = ...
```

But sometimes you want a non-string exception in which case you probably want `Control.Exception`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
-- ^^^ This is not just a comment, enables a language extension
import Control.Exception as X

data MyException = ZeroOrNegative
    deriving (Exception,Show,Eq,Ord)
              -- ^^ N.B. you should derive 'Exception' for
              --    types you want to 'throw'

pr n | n <= 0    = X.throw ZeroOrNegative
     | otherwise = ...
```